# How to send an array of objects along with other formdatas using ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I want to send an array of objects with other forms of data to MVC action using ajax.

```
var arr = [
    { Name: "a", IsActive: "true" },
    { Name: "b", IsActive: "false" },
    { Name: "c", IsActive: "true" },
    { Name: "d", IsActive: "false" },
    { Name: "e", IsActive: "true" }
];
```

and some other form fields data.
I tried getting and attaching form data like this:

```
    $(document.body).delegate("form#mainFormCreate", "submit", function () {

    var formData = new FormData($("form#mainFormCreate")[0]);
    var arr = [
            { Name: "a", IsActive: "true" },
            { Name: "b", IsActive: "false" },
            { Name: "c", IsActive: "true" },
            { Name: "d", IsActive: "false" },
            { Name: "e", IsActive: "true" }
    ];

    jQuery.each(arr, function (key, value) {
        formData.append('Features[' + key + ']', value);
    });
    $.ajax({
        url: '@Url.Action("CreateType", "Admin")',
        type: 'POST',
        data:formData,
        success: function (result) {
            ....

        },
        error: function (x, t, e) {
            ....
        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
    return false;
});
```

But in the server-side, I get an array of 5 elements with null values in Features property.
here is my server-side code. my object:

```
    public class ProductTypeCreateModel
   {

       public string ProductTypeName { get; set; }
       public List<Feature> Features { get; set; }
    }

    public class Feature
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    }
```

and my action:

```
    [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult CreateType(ProductTypeCreateModel productType)
        {
...
}
```

Thank.

Comment: Could you send us your post method in the Controller, at the same time you are ignoring the rules of the modelBinder.

Comment: It need to be in the format `formData.append( 'Features[0].Name', 'a');  formData.append( 'Features[0].IsActive', true);` etc (assuming `Features` is a complex object containing `string Name` and `bool IsActive`

Comment: thanks  Stephen, It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for the `DefaultModelBinder` to bind the data in the array, you need to append the name and values in the following format

```
formData.append('Features[0].Name', 'a');
formData.append('Features[0].IsActive', true);
formData.append('Features[1].Name', 'b');
formData.append('Features[1].IsActive', false);
... // etc
```

in exactly the same way that you would access the values in server side code (i.e. to get the `Name` of the second `Feature` in the collection, you would use

```
string name = productType.Features[1].Name; // returns "b"
```

The name of the parameter is `productType`, so just strip that, and whats left is how the name needs to be passed in `FormData`.

Answer (score 1):

Serialise your data first try JSON.stringify(formData)

Comment: by this i get completely null value for Features Property.

Answer (score 1):

You can either serialize of your data or just wrap it in an object and send it

```
var arr = [
        { Name: "a", IsActive: "true" },
        { Name: "b", IsActive: "false" },
        { Name: "c", IsActive: "true" },
        { Name: "d", IsActive: "false" },
        { Name: "e", IsActive: "true" }
];


$.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("CreateType", "Admin")',
    type: 'POST',
    data:{data: arr},
    success: function (result) {
        ....

    },
    error: function (x, t, e) {
        ....
    },
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false
});
```

Comment: what about my form data? I want to have form data AND my array's data.

Comment: you must add your formdata contents to the object (data: arr} or add array contents to the formdata.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following Code:

```
 $('form').serializeArray()` or  `$('form').serialize()
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *how* and/or *why* it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.